# C# exponential formula

Tags: c#, excel, exponential

I'm trying to find a way to write an exponential formula in C#.
I'm awfully bad in math I admit.

I have values linearly going from 10000 to 1 and need a formula to have results ranging from 400 to 1 but exponentially.

Example results I'dd like:

- 10000 -> 400
- 2000  -> 300
- 1000  -> 200
- 500   -> 100
- 100   -> 50
- 50    -> 10
- 10    -> 2
- 1     -> 1

Does not have to be those exact values, but that's the idea. How would I write a formula to give me those results?

Thanks for any help possible

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far? Also, you might explain a bit more what you want to achieve. For me, it's still unclear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: I guess you will have to _do_ the math...you're example values do not show a clear system, it's not really exponential and the ratios are differing and going up and down. It may be more helpful to explain the background, what you are _actually_ trying to achieve (the real world problem, not only the numbers).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to use `e^(value)`, This might help.

[Math.Exp Method (Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.exp(v=vs.110).aspx)

One example could be,

```
// Evaluate (e ^ X) ^ Y == e ^ (X * Y).
Console.WriteLine( 
    " Math.Pow(Math.Exp({0}), {1}) == {2:E16} \n"+
    " Math.Exp({0} * {1}) == {3:E16}",
    argX, argY, Math.Pow(Math.Exp(argX), argY),
    Math.Exp(argX * argY) );
```

Using this create a formula which provides required output.